# How to pass a string iterator to other functions

Tags: c++

I have this code which tries calling `count` with a `std::string` iterator but it fails with a compilation error.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int count(std::string::iterator iter, char ch)
{
    int n = 0;
    while (*iter == ch) {
        n++;
        iter++;
    }
    return n;
}

void search(std::string const& str, char ch)
{
    auto iter = std::find(str.begin(), str.end(), ch);
    
    if (iter != str.end()) {
        int n = count(iter, ch);
        std::cout << n << " consecutive '" << ch << "' found";
    } else {
        std::cout << "no char found";
    }
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        search(line, 'a');
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
00.cpp: In function 'void search(const string&, char)':
00.cpp:19:31: error: no matching function for call to 'count(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >&, char&)'
```

I found out that if I change the full type `std::string::iterator` to `auto` in function `count` and let the compiler infers the type it will work as expected (or at least I think it works). Why?

Comment: Note that once you get the code compiling, `count()` will still have *undefined behavior* if the `char` to count is at the end of the string. The loop doesn't know to stop looping once `iter` reaches the string's `end`, which can't be dereferenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str` is marked as `const`, then the iterator taken from it, i.e. the type of `iter` is `std::string::const_iterator`, which can't be converted to `std::string::iterator` implicitly and passed to `count`.

Since `count` won't modify element pointed by `iter`, you can make `count` taking `const_iterator` too.

```
int count(std::string::const_iterator iter, char ch)
```